# Hibernate issue : Field "..." doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am currently using Hibernate on a Spring environment and I am facing some issues.

In fact, I have 3 Entities :

- Criticite(id, description)
- Gravite(id, description)
- Occurrence(id, description)

What I am struggling with is the creation of a 4th table having foreign keys of the three others like this Crit_Grav_Occ(idC, idG, idO)

**Criticite**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "criticite")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "criticite")
public class Criticite implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "criticite")
    private Integer criticite;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "criticite_gravite_occurrence",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="criticites_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="occurrences_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<Occurrence> occurrences = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "criticite_gravite_occurrence",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="criticites_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="gravites_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<Gravite> gravites = new HashSet<>();
```

**Gravite**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gravite")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "gravite")
public class Gravite implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "gravites", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Criticite> criticites = new HashSet<>();
```

Occurrence

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "occurrence")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "occurrence")
public class Occurrence implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "occurrences", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Criticite> criticites = new HashSet<>();
```

And now... when I want to save a criticite using save from CrudRepository, I am getting a

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'occurrences_id' doesn't have
>   a default value

The weird thing above is this :

> Hibernate: insert into criticite_gravite_occurrence (criticites_id,
>   gravites_id) values (?, ?)

while I should expect this

> Hibernate: insert into criticite_gravite_occurrence (criticites_id,
>   gravites_id, occurences_id) values (?, ?, ?)

Any help is welcomed :)

Comment: I solved my problem! I actually started back from scratch and I found (thanks to hibernate forums) that I had to design it differently with @EmbeddeId in order to have composite primary key.